# Why my implementation of Promise.race isn't working?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

I have a task, where I should implement function Promise.race without using it itsef.

I've already found the code, which should work, but console throws an error

`"TypeError: promise is not a function"`.

```
function promiseRace(...promises) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    for(const promise of promises)
       promise.then(resolve, reject);
 })
};
```

I also tried this one, but it shows the same error (about p):

```
const promiseRace = (...promises) {
  new Promise((res, rej) => {
    promises.forEach(p => p.then(res).catch(rej));
  })
};
```

Does anyone know why is it not working?

Comment: My best guess is that one of the arguments passed down to `promiseRace` might not be a promise.

Comment: Can you give a min verifiable reproducible example we can play around with?

Comment: Use `Promise.resolve(promise).then(resolve, reject);` to make sure that you're working with a Promise before calling `.then`.

Comment: either use `Promise.resolve(promise).then` or `promise().then`. It largely depends what the function argument is anyway.

Comment: Your second function doesn't return the promise (and is missing the `=>`. After fixing that, both of these work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your latter example is missing the return statement on the 2nd line: `*return* new Promise(...`

Your first example works correctly (see below), but note that the standard `Promise.race` takes in an array param, whereas your implementation accepts variadic params:

```js
function promiseRace(...promises) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    for (const promise of promises)
      promise.then(resolve, reject);
  })
}

let slowPromise = new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => r('slow'), 2000));
let quickPromise = new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => r('quick'), 1000));

promiseRace(slowPromise, quickPromise).then(a => console.log('promiseRace', a));

Promise.race([slowPromise, quickPromise]).then(a => console.log('Promise.race', a));
```

Comment: As i said it's throwing an error that "promise is not a function", so it's not working correctly. What can be a reason ?

Comment: I've included a working example, i.e. it's working. Did you note my caveat regarding params? Can you provide a non-working example?